# Directive to disable and show load sign on a button during http-request

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Consider this runnable example http://plnkr.co/edit/a88cOYDVORDHQV3b5NGJ?p=preview

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.controller('myctrl',['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){
  $scope.myjson = [{title:'one'},{title:'two'},{title:'three'}];

  $scope.remove = function(idx){
    $scope.loading = true;
    $timeout(function(){ 
      $scope.myjson.splice(idx,1);
      $scope.loading = false
    }, 700)

  }
}])
.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
})
</script>

<div ng-controller="myctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="j in myjson">
  <a class="btn btn-default" 
  ng-bind-html=" loading? 
  ( '<i class=\'fa fa-refresh fa-spin\'></i>' | unsafe) : 
  ('Save' | unsafe)" 
  ng-disabled="loading"
  ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</a> 
  <b>{{j.title}}</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

The timeout is to simulate a http-request removing entities. This works if there is just one button (for example login or register). The problem is that each of the entities need to have their individual loading variable, and I don't know how to do it. I just want the button clicked on to show the loading symbol. For many buttons like this I think I need a directive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why they invented Angular directives.
You can create a directive with an isolated scope, and apply it to each of your buttons.

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.controller('myctrl',['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){
  $scope.myjson = [{title:'one'},{title:'two'},{title:'three'}];
}]).directive('loader',function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    controller: ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
      $scope.remove = function(idx){
        $scope.loading = true;
        $timeout(function(){ 
          $scope.myjson.splice(idx,1); 
          $scope.loading = false
        }, 700)

      }
    }]
  };
})
```

I've changed your plunkr to [demonstrate](http://plnkr.co/edit/2XosIGiHTJsjwHU56F0t?p=preview).

Comment: Thank's mate, I am learning the reason for using directives. Very nice, take a look here http://plnkr.co/edit/oPcl9BJeULtxRl7XZjcc?p=preview